# R - sqldf [Impute the closest value between two datasets with different dates]

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf

I am using sqldf in R to merge two datasets A & B (merge key 'id'), and need the weight values from B.
The rule is to get the closet date between A & B for each visit if no date matched.

1. DAY 2 in A will pick up the 'weight' from the record on '2021-03-10' in B
2. DAY 4 in A will pick up the 'weight' from the record on '2021-03-28' in B

Data A:

```
A <- read.table(text = "
    ord, id, Score,DATE, VISIT
    1,001,23,2021-03-01,DAY 0
    2,001,26,2021-03-03,DAY 1
    3,001,45,2021-03-10,DAY 2
    4,001,41,2021-03-20,DAY 3
    5,001,67,2021-03-26,DAY 4", header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Data B:

```
B <- read.table(text = "
    ord, id, Weight,DATE
    1,001,100,2021-03-01
    2,001,100.5,2021-03-03
    3,001,101,2021-03-06
    4,001,103,2021-03-20
    5,001,102,2021-03-28", header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Expected outcome:

```
A_B <- read.table(text = "
    ord, id, Score,DATE, VISIT, Weight
    1,001,23,2021-03-01,DAY 0,100
    2,001,26,2021-03-03,DAY 1,101
    3,001,45,2021-03-10,DAY 2,100.5
    4,001,41,2021-03-20,DAY 3,103
    5,001,67,2021-03-26,DAY 4,102", header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Comment: There is no '2021-03-10' in B. Does it need to be `sqldf` or `data.table` (much easier for this question) would be acceptable?

Comment: @Waldi Any methods work for me thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `nearest` rolling joins with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(A)
setDT(B)

A[,DATE:=as.Date(DATE)]
B[,DATE:=as.Date(DATE)]

B[A, .(ord,id,Score,DATE=i.DATE,VISIT,Weight),roll="nearest", on=.(id,DATE) ]
#>    ord id Score       DATE VISIT Weight
#> 1:   1  1    23 2021-03-01 DAY 0  100.0
#> 2:   2  1    26 2021-03-03 DAY 1  100.5
#> 3:   3  1    45 2021-03-10 DAY 2  101.0
#> 4:   4  1    41 2021-03-20 DAY 3  103.0
#> 5:   5  1    67 2021-03-26 DAY 4  102.0
```

If you're not familiar with `data.table`, I found this [tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html) useful to link the logic with `SQL`.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to select all columns in A other than using (ord,id,Score,DATE=i.DATE,VISIT,Weight) ?

Comment: `B[A,roll="nearest", on=.(id,DATE) ]`

Answer (score 1):

Perform a left join grouping on row id computing the minimum difference  between dates (diff) which as a side effect will pull in the row satisfying that minimum.

```
library(sqldf)

A$DATE <- as.Date(A$DATE)
B$DATE <- as.Date(B$DATE)

sqldf("select a.*, min(abs(a.DATE - b.DATE)) diff, b.Weight
  from A as a
  left join B as b using(id)
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  ord id Score       DATE VISIT diff Weight
1   1  1    23 2021-03-01 DAY 0    0  100.0
2   2  1    26 2021-03-03 DAY 1    0  100.5
3   3  1    45 2021-03-10 DAY 2    4  101.0
4   4  1    41 2021-03-20 DAY 3    0  103.0
5   5  1    67 2021-03-26 DAY 4    2  102.0
```